# Avoid re-ordering of windows when changing desktops/spaces

Tags: desktop, spaces

I use 4 desktops and have enabled `Assign to All Desktops` for several apps.  When changing from one desktop to another, any of these "all desktops" apps that were on top get sent to the back.  Can this be disabled?

In this gif, I have a terminal assigned to all desktops.  It appears momentarily when switching, and then gets sent backwards.  Extremely jarring and frustrating UX.

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/l4pTnCFvumFN9U2oU

Comment: I think you're fighting a basic tenet - that switching to a new Space will activate the last-used  app on that Space. Any app assigned to all Spaces for some reason is never the 'last-used app' on the Space you're moving to, even if it was on the Space you're leaving.

Comment: I don't see why there's any inherent reason that that behavior should be a "basic tenet".  That's why I'm looking for a setting to disable.  Moreover, that's not even the actual behavior.  The behavior is to activate the last non-all desktops app.  If you bring an all desktops app to the front before changing spaces it will still disappear when you come back.

Comment: Well, in any setup there's always someone somewhere who made a decision - that's the 'basic tenet'... & you're describing exactly what I said, moving from a space with an 'all spaces' app frontmost will bring forward the last one used on the space you're moving to, rather than the one you're bringing with you. Whether that's actually switchable behaviour, idk, I'm assuming not or someone would have found it by now. Wish you luck in your hunt.